# How to parse UTC date?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-6

I need to parse UTC date using **Delphi 6**:

```
2013-12-24T11:05:01.000+09:00
```

In **Delphi 7** I managed to do this with the following code:

1. Using `TXsDateTime`:

   ```
   var
    utcTime : TXsDateTime;
    localTime : TDateTime;
    temp : string;
   begin
    temp := '2013-12-24T00:00:00.000-02:00';
    utcTime.XSToNative(temp);
    localTime := utcTime.AsUTCDateTime; // get time in +00:00 timezone
    localTime := IncHour(localTime, 9); // het time local timezone
    //...
   end;
   ```
2. Using `StrToDateTime` overload with `TFormatSettings`:

   ```
   var
     localTime : TDateTime;
     temp, datetimePart : string;
     formatSettings : TFormatSettings;
   begin
    temp := '2013-12-24T00:00:00.000+01:00';
    //init format settings
    GetLocaleFormatSettings(LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, formatSettings);
    formatSettings.DateSeparator := '-';
    formatSettings.ShortDateFormat := 'yyyy-MM-dd';
    //parse datetime
    datetimePart := StringReplace(copy(temp,1,Length(temp)-10),'T',' ',[]);
    localTime := StrToDateTime(datetimePart, formatSettings);
    //get datetime in +00:00 timezone
    localTime := IncHour(localTime, -1*strtoint(copy(temp,Length(temp)-5,3)));
    localTime := IncMinute(localTime, -1*strtoint(copy(temp,Length(temp)-1,2)));
    //get datetime in local timezone
    localTime := IncHour(localTime , 9);
    //...
   end;
   ```

But in Delphi 6:

1. I cannot even call `XSToNative`, as it throws `EConvertError` misplacing month and day parts of the date; and also `TXsDateTime` does not contain definition for `AsUTCDateTime`...
2. `SysUtils` does not contain definition for `TFormatSettings` and consequently the overload of `StrToDateTime` I use is unavailable.

Is there anything I am missing, or what else can I use to parse this format in **Delphi 6**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I used `EncodeDateTime` function:

```
var
 time1, time2 : TDateTime;
 year,month,day,hour,minute,second,mlsecond, hourOffset, minOffset : integer;
 temp :string;
begin
 temp := '2013-12-24T00:00:00.000-09:30';
 //parse separate parts of the datetime
 year := strtoint(copy(temp,1,4));
 month := strtoint(copy(temp,6,2));
 day := strtoint(copy(temp,9,2));
 hour := strtoint(copy(temp,12,2));
 minute := strtoint(copy(temp,15,2));
 second := strtoint(copy(temp,18,2));
 mlsecond := strtoint(copy(temp,21,3));
 hourOffset := strtoint(copy(temp,25,2));
 minOffset := strtoint(copy(temp,28,2));
 //adjust timezone offset sign
 if(temp[24]='+')then
 begin
  hourOffset := -1 * hourOffset;
  minOffset := -1 * minOffset;
 end;
 //get time in the +00:00 timezone
 time1 := EncodeDateTime(year,month,day,hour,minute,second,mlsecond);
 time1 := IncHour(time1, hourOffset);
 time1 := IncMinute(time1, minOffset);
 //get time in local timezone
 time2 := IncHour(time1, 9);
 //...
end;
```

Comment: I'm not sure a `copy(temp,9,2)` (for example) approach is reliable. What if there is a space at the beginning of the string, or a one-digit month, or...?  It is probably better to parse it into pieces, split at dashes, colons, etc.

Comment: If the input doesn't match the function's domain, then all bets are off, @David, but that's the case for all functions. The domain of this function is strings in the ISO 8601 format; leading spaces and one-digit months are outside the set of valid inputs.